# Delegate from asynchronous callback

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, callback

```
Private Sub Receiving(ByVal iAr As IAsyncResult)
    Dim nChar As Integer
    Dim newStr As String
    Try
        SyncLock client.GetStream
            Try
                nChar = client.GetStream.EndRead(iAr)
            Catch
                Console.WriteLine("exciting")
                Exit Sub
            End Try
        End SyncLock
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("exciting")
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    newStr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bByte, 0, nChar)

    TextBox3.Text = newStr

    client.GetStream.BeginRead(bByte, 0, 4096, AddressOf Receiving, Nothing)
End Sub
```

I have this code and I'm trying to write in the textbox 3 I know I need to use a delegate because the textbox is in the main thread and the callback run in a seperate one but how do I create i, I'm really confused. I know how to do it for a simple thread but since it's the first time I used asynchronous callback I don't know how to make this could I get some help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give a check at that solution from MSDN [Thread-Safe call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You first need to create a method to access the textbox like this :

```
Private Sub SetText(ByVal [text] As String)

 ' InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
 ' calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
 ' If these threads are different, it returns true.
 If Me.textBox3.InvokeRequired Then
     Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
     Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {[text]})
 Else
     Me.textBox3.Text = [text]
 End If
End Sub
```

Then you call this from your thread method :

```
Private Sub Receiving(ByVal iAr As IAsyncResult)
Dim nChar As Integer
Dim newStr As String
Try
    SyncLock client.GetStream
        Try
            nChar = client.GetStream.EndRead(iAr)
        Catch
            Console.WriteLine("exciting")
            Exit Sub
        End Try
    End SyncLock
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine("exciting")
    Exit Sub
End Try

newStr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bByte, 0, nChar)

SetText(newStr) ' Here you make the call

client.GetStream.BeginRead(bByte, 0, 4096, AddressOf Receiving, Nothing)
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!